# Scala inner type under lattice inheritance

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance, inner-classes

Consider the following code:

```
trait A {
  trait T
  def t: T
}
trait B1 extends A {
  trait T extends super.T
  def t: T
}
trait B2 extends A {
  trait T extends super.T
  def t: T
}
trait C extends B1 with B2 {
  trait T extends super.T // super.T means only B2.T, not B1.T
  //trait T extends B1.T with B2.T // Actually I want to do this
  def t: T
}
```

This will occur a compile error because type `T` in trait `C` doesn't inherit `B1.T`. But in trait `C`, I can't get `B1.T` by calling `super.T`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with literally just saying `trait T extends B1.T with B2.T`?

Comment: That won't compile because `T` is path dependent type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala you can refer to the specific superclass you want:

```
trait C extends B1 with B2 {
  trait T extends super[B1].T with super[B2].T
  def t: T
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By defining a `type T1` in `B1`, I can resolve this problem:

```
trait A {
  trait T
  def t: T
}
trait B1 extends A {
  trait T extends super.T
  protected type T1 = T
  def t: T
}
trait B2 extends A {
  trait T extends super.T
  def t: T
}
trait C extends B1 with B2 {
  trait T extends super.T with T1
  def t: T
}
```